# Native way for PL/SQL package to write to kafka topic

Tags: oracle, plsql, apache-kafka, dbms-job

I have been looking for native ways for a Oracle PL/SQL program/procedure output to a Kafka topic directly. Please advise if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, may be helpful:

[Kafka with Oracle](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/spatial/pdf/OOW2018_Query_Real-Time_Kafka_Streams_with_Oracle_SQL.pdf)

[Oracle SQL Access to Kafka](https://docs.oracle.com/en/bigdata/big-data-sql/4.1/bdsug/oracle-sql-access-kafka.html#GUID-33BED0F0-0DF0-4338-990C-7DF1AE7B1E37)

[Querying and Publishing Kafka Events from Oracle Database SQL and PL/SQL](https://technology.amis.nl/database/querying-and-publishing-kafka-events-from-oracle-database-sql-and-pl-sql/)